# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, top-7, promotion

One of the big 7 questions.

- One sugestion per answer, please

Answer (score 6):

If people here are very active on board game forums, they could put a link in their signature.

Answer (score 4):

**"Stump the Stack"**

- Contact convention organizers.  See if they'd like one of us to attend and volunteer to field any board game questions.  In exchange, we will publicize the event here and drum up "support" to answer their questions quickly.
- Have our volunteer assist folks in signing up for an account here, or just enter the question directly.
- Make sure each person leaves with a business card containing the url https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/X (where X is the question number).  Ask them to check that URL later on, or swing back in an hour.

That's the basic plan, I know the larger conventions would definitely want $$ in order for us to participate in any official fashion, but there are a ton of smaller conventions that may be open to this plan.

Answer (score 3):

When public beta will be launched, every meta user must post about this site in Twitter. I can bet that at least 3 new users will come from my followers.

Facebook is also welcome (my Twitter account is synchronized with FB).

Comment: Twitter was my plan also.

Answer (score 2):

When a new game comes out, we should immediately make an effort to post a bunch of questions about that game, and then take the time to post good answers.  It will help us capture the "opening-weekend" crowd of people trying to settle arguments with their shiny new games via google.

"Can I use a froob in conjunction with a squark?"

"Dunno, google it?"

"According to this board games site, you can only use a froob with a squark if you fleech it first."

"Cool.  Hey, they have a bunch of other answers here too!"

"Oh, sweet!  Send me the link!"

Answer (score 0):

What about designing a game featuring the site and distribute that.

The SO concept has been compared with mass player games. But It can be turned into a boardgame too.

Of course the system must be simplified, but the bottom line is to collect rep points and use the new privileges. (And no rep is not the main part but you can compare the game to the site as munchkin to rpg's).

Answer (score 0):

Participate in PAX (Penny Arcade Expo) forums (http://forums.penny-arcade.com/).  The content of this exposition is very much user driven.