# Is this question on topic and if so, what's the appropriate tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/40491/game-with-changing-goal) was recently asked and I was looking for a better tag as [identify-this-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) doesn't really suit it. I went through several pages of tags and couldn't find anything suitable.

I then checked the meta of what is on topic, and I wasn't sure if it's even on topic? It could be coming across as a game recommendation question, but it's not clear cut.

Is it on topic? If so, what tag should it use?

Comment: Seems extremely broad to me

Comment: Found the answer, looks like this [meta question and answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/is-this-a-game-recommendation-question?rq=1) pretty much confirms what I thought